# bootstrap - how to default to show modal instead of using button

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

From [Bootstrap website](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/modal/), it always use button to show the modal.

I am using React, so I want to use javascript manipulate whether the modal shows.

Is there any way to make the modal show as default?

Modal.js

```
...
return(
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
)
```

```
import "./styles.css";
import Modal from './Model'

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>123</h1>
      <Modal/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: you can use the modal show state to programmatically open it

Comment: @Greedo I tried to update to `<div class="modal show" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">, but it doen't shows

Comment: You have to use the react state, like in this example: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/modal/#modal-default-sizing

Comment: You may just want to move over to a more React-friendly UI component library. Vanilla Bootstrap is extremely dated for React usage. Even REact-Boostrap has fallen out of favor. Look at Material-UI, Antd, ... more, all easily found by googling for "react component library".

Comment: `import Modal from './Model'`  shouldn't be `from './Modal` ?  also there is bootstrap for react . Check here https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/modal/ . No need to just copy paste the html of a bs modal inside a react component. Also, react uses JSX, you added plain html.

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery to show or hide

```
   $("#id of your modal").modal("show"); 
   $("#id of your modal").modal("hide");
```

jQuery must be referenced first . before the bootstrap
if you wanna use pure javascript only you can change it manually like bellow:

```
  <!-- Modal -->
<div id="mymodal">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" id="close-btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                ...
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button id="close-btn" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>

    // select close  buttons
    const mymodal = document.getElementById('mymodal');
    const close_btn = document.querySelectorAll("#close-btn");

    //show the modal 
    mymodal.style.display = "block"


    //close modal function 
    function hide() {
        mymodal.style.display = "none"
    }

    //clise the modal when you click the close btns
    close_btn.forEach(close => {
        close.addEventListener("click", hide)
    })
</script>
```

and change the script in order you want